# Is there a way to print value from internal code in Cucumber Report?

Tags: java, cucumber, gherkin, cucumber-java, cucumber-serenity

Is there any way to print out some internal code values from Java code to appear in Cucumber Report?

There is one integer value inside step definition file of Cucumber that is being implemented on Java code (transaction ID) which I need to display on Cucumber Report. Usually the Cucumber report only displays the Gherkin language of feature files.

Is there any way that I can display transaction ID on Cucumber Report?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use Cucumber Hooks to get the scenario and then use log on it.
Something like:

```
class Steps {
    Scenario scenario;

    @Before
    public void beforeScenario(Scenario scenario) { 
        this.scenario = scenario;
    }

    @Then("Internal Data is logged")
    public void logging() {
        scenario.log("transactionId");
    }
}
```